# Edit Dataset's CommandText

Tags: c#, .net, dataset, runtime, strongly-typed-dataset

How can I edit `Dataset's` (`.xsd file`) Query's `CommandText` in Runtime mode ?

How can give new sql query ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is not the Dataset that contains the CommandText, it is the DataAdapter which contains 4 commands :

```
public sealed class SqlDataAdapter
{
    public SqlCommand DeleteCommand { get; set; }
    public SqlCommand InsertCommand { get; set; }
    public SqlCommand SelectCommand { get; set; }
    public SqlCommand UpdateCommand { get; set; }
}
```

For example, if you want to change the select sql :

```
var dataset = new MyDataSet();
var adapter = new MyTableAdapter();
adapter.Adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM FOO";
adapter.Fill(dataset.MyTable);
```